# Крашится SSH соединение JetBrains

Tags: intellij-idea, ssh, jetbrains

возникла проблема с использованием удалённой разработки на IntelliJ IDEA. Подключаюсь к Ubuntu 22.04 корректно, выбираю IDE IntelliJ IDEA и выбираю директорию для проектов /media (случайную выбрал), далее скачиваю IDE и подключаюсь. Идёт кратковременный процесс работы, после чего выбрасывает на главную страницу без какого-либо окна ошибки. Логи прикрепил. По итогу на сервере создает файл размером в 1.8 МБ и не более. Пробовал удалять папку и заново начинать процесс, не помогает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибку разработчики IDE исправили в версии 2022.3, дополнительно выставив минимальные условия операционной системы для запуска удаленной разработки.